# Karma: Permission Denied when building tests in Travis CI

Tags: npm, travis-ci, karma-mocha

My unit tests are building fine locally when i run my tests script in npm.

Here is my script :-

```
"test": "karma start test/unit/karma.config.js --single-run"
```

My Karma Config :-

```
var webpackConfig = require('../../build/webpack.test.config.js')
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'sinon-chai'],
    files: ['./index.js'],
    preprocessors: {
      './index.js': ['webpack']
    },
    plugins: [
      'karma-mocha',
      'karma-sinon-chai',
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
      'karma-webpack'
    ],
    webpack: webpackConfig,
    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true
    }
  })
}
```

When Travis CI attempts to run the same npm script, against my public GitHub repository, i get the following error :-

[image: Build Logs from travis CI]

Here is my Travis config :-

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "7.5"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've resolved this issue.

For anyone else that ends up with this issue, make sure you don't accidently check in your node_modules folder in GitHub.

If you do, i think Travis CI tries to run npm against the Karma node_module in your repo.

When you remove them, Travis handles it internally.

I should never have had the node_modules folder in source control.

School Boy Error.